# Can't understand how to complete this ARM Assembly code to do the sum of 5 numbers and the mean of the remainders

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to learn ARM Assembly and I found this exercise and trying to solve it.

I did this piece of code but I don't really know how to fix and continue it, as I know some parts are missing. I first tried to do the sum part, but can't understand how to do the first 5 numbers and the the mean of the others.

This is the exercise:

**Given a vector V[] of N=21 positive integers, store the variables starting from the memory location 0x100.**

**-Calculate the sum of the first 5 numbers, and the calculates the mean of the remainders.**

**-Identify the greater and the lesser of the two values ​​obtained and store the first in position 0x200 and the second in the 0x500 position.**

This is the code I made I'm trying to complete and fix:

```
ENTRY
    MOV R0, #21         ; Counter for array
    LDR R1, =array      ; Register for array
loop    LDR R2, [R1], #20   ; Loading value from array and updating(increment) the address
    ADD R3,R3,R2        ; Sum is stored in R3 register
    SUB R0,R0,#1        ; Decrementing counter value
    CMP R0,#00          ; Checking counter value
    BNE loop
    END
```

EDIT: I worked something out and this is the result, not final as I have to check if it works properly on my machine.

```
            MOV R0, #21                 ; Counter array
            LDR R1, =array, #0x100      ; Array at 0x100
loopsum   LDR R2, [R1], #20           ; Loading value from array and updating(increment) the address
            ADD R3,R3,R2                ; Put sum in R3
            SUB R0,R0,#1                ; decrease counter
            CMP R0,#16                  ; check if first 5
            Bne loopsum

loopmean   LDR R2, [R1], #16           ; Loading value from array and updating(increment) the address
            ADD R4,R4,R2                ; put sum in R4
            SUB R0,R0,#1                ; decrease counter
            CMP R0,#0                   ; check if ended
            Bne loopmean

            MOV R4, R4, ASR 16          ;divide by 16
            MOV R5, #0x200              ;address for max
            MOV R6, #0x500              ;address for min

            CMP R3, R4                  ;R3 > R4 ?
            MOVgt R5, R3                ;if yes puts R3 in R5
            MOVle R6, R4                ;R4 in R6

            CMP R4, R3                  ;R4 > R3 ?
            MOVgt R5, R4                ;if yes puts R4 in R5
            Movle R6, R3                ;R3 in R6

            END
```

Comment: _"can't understand how to do the first 5 numbers and the the mean of the others"_ You have a loop counter that you're decrementing. If the counter is greater than some value, add the element to one register (the sum), otherwise add it to another (which you'll use for the mean).

Comment: Also keep in mind that your mean will be calculated based on 16 elements, which is a power of 2, which eliminates the need for a proper division instruction.

Comment: @Michael Ok thanks, I will work on it and post what comes out

Comment: Why not initializing R3 with 0??; `LDR R2, [R1], #20` Why `#20` and not `#4`???;  `ASR #16` is dividing a SIGNED value by 65536, you should use `LSR #4`;

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE
;I didn't initialize it as my professor never did in his slides; I choose 20 as I have an array of 21 elem., and have to go through the first 5; Oh ok I didn't know, so it divides by n^2 I guess; Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I understand what your professor is trying to teach, but he should be teaching `AAPCS` first, and how to make the routines to proper separate functions IMO.

Below are three function:

- void myFunc(uint32_t *pArray, uint32_t *pLesser, uint32_t *pGreater);
- void myFunc_mf(uint32_t *pArray, uint32_t *pLesser, uint32_t *pGreater);
- void myFunc_bfmf(uint32_t *pArray, uint32_t *pLesser, uint32_t *pGreater);

As the parameter names suggest, you should call them by the parameters 0x100, 0x500, and 0x200 each in order to meet your professor's requirements

The first one (myFunc) is probably what your professor would expect: running loops.

The second and third ones are showing the middle finger (and a big fu**ing one) to this somewhat stupid and unrealistic assignment by showing how a real assembly programmer would deal with this problem on ARM integer core or NEON.

And notice that the neon version is the shortest one.

```
    .syntax unified
    .arm
    .arch   armv7-a
    .fpu    neon
    .global myFunc, myFunc_mf, myFunc_bfmf
    .text


.balign 64
.func
// void myFunc(uint32_t *pArray, uint32_t *pLesser, uint32_t *pGreater);

pArray  .req    r0
pLesser .req    r1
pGreater    .req    r2
counter .req    r3
sum     .req    r12
mean1   .req    r6
mean2   .req    r7
lesser  .req    pArray
greater .req    mean2


myFunc:
    push    {r4-r7}
    mov     counter, #5
    mov     sum, #0
    mov     mean1, #0
    mov     mean2, #0
    b       1f

.balign 64
1:
    ldr     r4, [pArray], #4
    subs    counter, counter, #1
    add     sum, sum, r4
    bne     1b

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    mov     counter, #16
    b       1f

.balign 64
1:
    ldrd    r4, r5, [pArray], #8
    subs    counter, counter, #2
    add     mean1, mean1, r4
    add     mean2, mean2, r5
    bne     1b

    add     mean1, mean2, mean1
    lsr     mean1, mean1, #4

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    cmp     mean1, sum
    mov greater, mean1
    mov lesser, sum
    movlo   greater, sum
    movlo   lesser, mean1

    str     greater, [pGreater]
    str     lesser, [pLesser]

    pop     {r4-r7}
    bx      lr
.endfunc

.balign 64
.func
myFunc_mf:
    push    {r4-r11}

    ldmia   pArray!, {r4-r8}
    add     r4, r5, r4
    add     r6, r7, r6
    add     r4, r4, r8
    add     r3, r4, r6

    ldmia   pArray!, {r4-r11}
    add     r4, r5, r4
    add     r6, r7, r6
    add     r8, r9, r8
    add     r10, r11, r10
    add     r4, r6, r4
    add     r8, r10, r8
    add     r12, r8, r4

    ldmia   pArray, {r4-r11}
    add     r4, r5, r4
    add     r6, r7, r6
    add     r8, r9, r8
    add     r10, r11, r10
    add     r4, r6, r4
    add     r8, r10, r8

    add     r12, r4, r12
    add     r12, r12, r8
    lsr     r12, r12, #4

    cmp     r12, r3
    mov r4, r12
    mov r5, r3
    movlo   r4, r3
    movlo   r5, r12

    str     r4, [pGreater]
    str     r5, [pLesser]

    pop     {r4-r11}
    bx      lr
.endfunc

.balign 64
.func
myFunc_bfmf:
    vmov.i32    d2, #0
    vld1.32     {q0}, [pArray]!
    vld1.32     {d2[0]}, [pArray]!
    vld1.32     {q2, q3}, [pArray]!
    vld1.32     {q8, q9}, [pArray]

    vpaddl.u32  q0, q0
        vpaddl.u32  q2, q2
        vpaddl.u32  q3, q3
    vpadal.u32  d0, d2
        vpadal.u32  q2, q8
        vpadal.u32  q3, q9
    vadd.u64    d0, d0, d1
        vadd.u64    q2, q3, q2
        vadd.u64    d4, d5, d4
        vshr.u64    d1, d4, #4

    vmax.u32    d2, d1, d0
    vmin.u32    d3, d1, d0

    vst1.32     {d2[0]}, [pGreater]
    vst1.32     {d3[0]}, [pLesser]

    bx      lr
.endfunc
.end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you spent understanding and writing your solution, it seems very complete and very well written.


I'm a bit confused reading the code, as it is widely different from other  exercises solutions from the professor and some code parts I never seen from his slides.
I will read it carefully step by step and understand it, thank you

Comment: @Cinciullain `ldrd` will cause an alignment fault exception on armv5(arm9) or below. Replace that line with `ldmia pArray!, {r4, r5}`